# I moved my eclipse workspace, and now all my files are missing src

Tags: eclipse, file

Long story short, I switched computers, and literally just copied my entire *workspace* folder into a flash drive, and when I tried to apply it to my new computer by clicking import> Existing projects into workspace > Select archive file. This is how they look when i try to view them:

http://prntscr.com/daj38x

While they should look like this:

http://prntscr.com/daj4fk

Am I doing something wrong while importing these files? Please help, I want to code again ;(

Comment: As you've learned (the hard way), Eclipse workspaces are NOT portable and not intended to be moved around. It's trivial to export or share *projects* however - that's what you need to do. Do you still have access to the initial computer where you got the workspace from?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the source folder (in the 1st screenshot). Notice that there's a `src` folder in the 2nd picture (along with the `.settings` folder).

I think there is also a good chance you're missing the `.project` and `.classpath` files, no?

This has also happened to me when trying to copy entire projects from one machine to another. You could create a new project and copy the classes, but I think that would be quite time consuming.

Comment: Well, what worked for me was creating a new project and copy/pasting the code from your old classes to new classes. It might be time consuming depending on how large your old project was, but I haven't found a better solution...